# Do primary sources unequivocally record coming of the Moshiach and establishing world order

Tags: parshanut-torah-comment, tanach, rambam, messiah

Do the primary sources like Torah , tanach record the elaborate and supernatural propheises concerning the Moshiach? Rambam and talmud has described the qualities of Moshiach but do the primary sources also record his coming with the same characteristics and grandeur as described by rambam. Please cite the relevant verses that justify the talmudinic or rambam opinions.

Comment: The very end of Devarim has a bit on Mashiach. Also the late nevi'im, mostly in Trei Asar.

Comment: Isaiah 10:32-12:6 see http://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/2859/jewish/Isaiah-on-Moshiach.htm

Comment: Keep in mind that according to Jewish tradition, the Oral Torah was given together with the Written Torah. Many people would therefore consider the Talmud, and arguably even the Rambam, a primary source, since even though they were codified thousands of years after the Revelation at Sinai, they were based on the Oral Torah that was given then.

Comment: There is a list of primary sources here: http://www.jewfaq.org/m/mashiach.htm

Answer (score 1):

While there are many sources that describe the Messianic era in Tanach (and would require more time investment to provide a more complete response), one of the sources I would recommend you look at is in the 11th Chapter of the Book of Yeshayah (which ray refers to, as well). That chapter describes how the Mashiach will be on a uniquely high spiritual level (able to judge cases correctly due to the special wisdom granted to him by HaShem), how even the most dangerous animals will not pose a threat (miraculously), and later on describes some of the miracles related the coming of the Messianic Era. In addition, the description of Mashiach's  ability to simply sense the guilty party in a case (Rava in Sanhedrin, 93b) and other characteristics unique to Mashiach (see Verses 1 - 5) provide clear guidelines of some of what is necessary for one to be Mashiach and should give pause to those who wish to proclaim any individual the Mashiach. Even Bar Kochba who, while alive, was believed by many to be Mashiach (including Rabbi Akiva), was recognized as not being the Mashiach once he died (regardless of whether he possessed the potential of being the Mashiach while still alive).

Comment: That's a machlokes Rambam and Raavad

Comment: Those are not primary sources.

Comment: @Adel Are you referring to my answer or to the comment on my answer? In my answer I quoted the Book of Yeshayah (Isaiah), certainly a primary source. In the Tanach, there are numerous primary sources for the Mashiach and the Messianic era. In fact, religions that followed Judaism pick up many ideas from Judaism. For example, Islam's belief in the Messiah (Mahdi) was preceded by Judaism and the prophecies of Jewish prophets by roughly 1500 years (and this is just in reference to those prophets). For example the non-Jewish prophet Bilaam prophesied about the Messiah (as recorded in The Torah):-)